# File Upload in Google Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension to upload a file to an external API. It works great when I test it out on a separate tab. The problem comes when adding it as a popup.

When you go to select a file on OS X the popup closes because the user has focussed away from the extension. I understand this is expected behaviour, most of the time the user will be wanting the popup to close when moving away so I guess my question is — is there a work around for this?

[image: Here's the extension]

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find some solution?

Comment: I used JS to inject a window into the page instead of using the popover.  http://sht.tl/DRIO

Comment: And what do you do next? get the value of file input?